# How to set s3 copy command in zsh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zsh, aws-cli

I created `s3.zsh` like following,

I'd like to upload data to redshift from s3.

```
#!/bin/zsh
aws s3 (copy test.table
from 's3://mybucket/test.txt'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/Copy'
timeformat as 'auto'
delimiter '\t')
```

And I tried `zsh s3.zsh`. but it returned following

`s3.zsh:3: number expected`

How to run my zsh with aws cli ?

If someone has opinion, please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To load data from Amazon S3 to Amazon Redshift, you would use the [COPY command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) (as you have shown in brackets).

However, this command needs to be sent to the Redshift database, not the S3 service.

There are two ways to send commands to an Amazon Redshift database:

- By using an SQL client to login to Redshift and then issue the COPY command, or
- By [Using the Amazon Redshift Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html), which can execute commands on the database (such as COPY) via an API call authenticated via IAM credentials

Amazon Redshift will 'pull' the data from S3, rather than S3 'pushing' the data to Redshift.